# GreenDroid Activity and YouTubeBaseActivity is possible?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, greendroid

I have a app working where I use GreenDroid to set StatusBar with GDActivity. I want to add a youtube video with its API.

The problem is that I can't use GDActivity and YouTubeBaseActivity in the same Activity.

Are there any solution?

Thanks.